# Distinct one column return selected columns and order by date desc using sybase

Tags: numbers, row, sybase

Hi Guys i have a problem on how im going to distinct single column and return selected column

```
Ac_no ord_status order_no
12334    PL         1
12334    ML         2
12334    CL         3
64543    PL         1
65778    JL         6
83887    CL         4
83887    KL         3

Ac_no ord_statu sorder_no
12334    CL        3
64543    PL        1
65778    JL        6
83887    CL        4
```

i want to see that result

here is my sample or code but unfortunately the code didnt work in sybase 1.2.0.637

SELECT Ac_no, ord_status, order_no 
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY Ac_no order by ord_status)rm 
      from wo_order)x
      where x = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you want to display, for each `Ac_no` group of records, the single record having the lowest `ord_status`.  You were on the right track, but you need to restrict the subquery using the alias you defined for the row number:

```
SELECT Ac_no, ord_status, order_no
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ac_no ORDER BY ord_status) rn
    FROM wo_order
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Here is a version which should run on your version of Sybase, even without using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT w1.Ac_no, w1.ord_status, w1.order_no
FROM wo_order w1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Ac_no, MIN(ord_status) AS min_ord_status
    FROM wo_order
    GROUP BY Ac_no
) w2
    ON w1.Ac_no = w2.Ac_no AND
       w1.ord_status = w2.min_ord_status;
```

Comment: Then perhaps your early version of Sybase does not support it.  It might be time to upgrade.

Comment: is there a possible way to distinct one column and return multiple column that support my sybase version?

Comment: @Drin Check my updated answer for a workaround which avoids `ROW_NUMBER`.  That being said, if you have needs for these types of queries, you should really conside upgrading, if that would be under your control.

Answer (score 0):

Should work without a window function:

```
select t1.* from wo_order t1,
(select max(order_no) order_no, ac_no from wo_order group by ac_no) t2
where 
  t1.ac_no=t2.ac_no
  and t1.order_no=t2.order_no
```